# Help Saving Custom Post Type Meta Box

Tags: custom-post-types

I have the following code used to create a Custom Post Type. All works the save function is being triggered, and it seems to be saving. But I cannot get the saved data to output in the text field on Page Edit. I've stared at this and played around with it for days now. Looked at every tutorial online. I can't figure out what I am missing here. Any help would be great appreciated.

I tried changing the `10,2` but doesn't help. I tried writing new code in the save function that you can see is commented out and this doesn't work either.

```
// Registers the new post type and taxonomy
function course_listing_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'courses',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Course Listings' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Course Listing' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New Course' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Course Listing' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Course Listing' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'Add New Course Listing' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Course Listing' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Course Listing' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No Course Listings found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Course Listings found in trash' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => "courses"), // Permalinks format
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'taxonomies'    => array( 'regional', 'national', 'global'), //figure out how to show this
            'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_course_listing'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'course_listing_posttype' );

// Add Meta Boxes
function add_course_listing() {
    //meta for application deadline
    add_meta_box('course_listing_meta', 'Course Listing Details', 'course_listing_meta', 'courses', 'normal', 'default');
}
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_course_listing");

//application deadline meta
function course_listing_meta($object) {
    global $post; 
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), "meta-box-nonce");
    ?>

    <label for="application_deadline"><strong>Application Deadline:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Select the deadline for the course application</i><br>
    <input type="text" id="application_deadline" name="application_deadline" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'application_deadline', true); ?>" size="120">
    <br><br>

    <label for="workshop_date"><strong>On-Site Workshop Dates:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Lorem ipsum dorem doleorum fibrouich forloer kolem lorey</i><br>
    <input type="text" id="workshop_date" name="workshop_date" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'workshop_date', true); ?>" size="120">
    <br><br>

    <label><strong>Contact Information:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Lorem ipsum dorem doleorum fibrouich forloer kolem lorey</i><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="contact_information" name="contact_information" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'contact_information', true); ?>" rows="10" cols="120"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <label><strong>Directions:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Lorem ipsum dorem doleorum fibrouich forloer kolem lorey</i><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="directions" name="directions" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'directions', true); ?>" rows="10" cols="120"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <label><strong>Hotels and Lodging:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Lorem ipsum dorem doleorum fibrouich forloer kolem lorey</i><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="lodging" name="lodging" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'lodging', true); ?>" rows="10" cols="120"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <label><strong>Veterinarians Nearby:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Lorem ipsum dorem doleorum fibrouich forloer kolem lorey</i><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="veterinarians" name="veterinarians" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'veterinarians', true); ?>" rows="10" cols="120"></textarea>
    <br><br>

    <label><strong>State:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Lorem ipsum dorem doleorum fibrouich forloer kolem lorey</i><br>
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'state', true); ?>" size="120">
    <br><br>

    <label><strong>Zip Code:</strong></label><br>
    <i>Lorem ipsum dorem doleorum fibrouich forloer kolem lorey</i><br>
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" value="<?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'zip', true); ?>" size="120">
    <br><br>

<?php
}

// Save the Metabox Data
function wpt_save_events_meta($post_id, $post) {
        /*
        if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
            return $post_id;

        if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
            return $post_id;
        */
        //global $post;

        if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
            return $post_id;

        /*
        $slug = "post";
        if($slug != $post->post_type)
            return $post_id;
        */

        $meta_box_text_value = "";
        $meta_box_dropdown_value = "";
        $meta_box_checkbox_value = "";

        if ( isset( $_POST['contact_information'] ) && $_POST['contact_information'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $meta_box_text_value, 'courses', $_POST['contact_information'] );
        }


        /*
        //save workshop date
        if(isset($_POST["contact_information"]))
        {
            $meta_box_text_value  = $_POST["contact_information"];
        }
        update_post_meta($post_id, "contact_information", $meta_box_text_value);
        */
}
add_action('save_post', 'wpt_save_events_meta', 10, 2); // save the custom fields
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your `update_post_meta` variables.

It should be: `update_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value);`
Here `$prev_value` is optional. [Full details here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Comment: doesn't seem to fix the issue unfortunately. still values are not showing. is this an issue where the value is full and i need to flush it or something to work now that i've tried so many times?

Comment: values are posting and saving just fine. they are just not showing the actual value on page edit for the 'value' field

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you have a "value" field for textarea. It should be like this:

```
<textarea id="workshop_date" name="workshop_date_cl" rows="10" cols="120"><?php echo get_post_meta($object->ID, 'workshop_date_cl', true); ?></textarea>
```